# Issue with AutoComplete using TextBox in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I have the following code which only works when looking up the first 3 characters at the **start** of the line. However, I want to be able to show AutoComplete data by searching anywhere in the line.

```
private void txtCMDestination_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
        if (t != null)
        {
            if (t.Text.Length >= 3)
            {
                var arr = IndexItems.Where(x => x.ToUpper().Contains(t.Text.ToUpper())).ToArray();
                var collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                collection.AddRange(arr);
                txtCMDestination.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Cheers.

**EDIT**

I have debugged to ensure that `var arr` contains filtered data when I type in the 3 chars and it does. So my LINQ is working as expected, which leads to me to believe there is something wrong with `txtCMDestination.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;` receiving the collection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779557/dynamically-changing-textboxs-autocomplete-list-causes-accessviolationexception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018029/autocomplete-texbox-error-write-to-protected-memory

Comment: What is the question? Is your issue that the AC dropdown doesn't show? I'm afraid it insists on looking only at the start just like it insists on sorting by alphabet, no matter what you feed in.. So you may have to work around with a fully coded solution.

Comment: @TaW thanks for the reply. My question is exactly that, how can I get it to look in the middle of a string rather than the start. I am able to get the list filtered, it does not drop down though. Is there a way to drop down/show the list manually?

Comment: As I recall, there is a `SendMessage` API `CB_SHOWDROPDOWN` with ComboBox, but is there something similar for using TextBox?

Comment: What about something like this?

http://net-informations.com/q/faq/autocomplete.html